# most efficient way to generate sound with web audio api

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api, audiocontext

I'm building an fm synth with some effects using the web audio api. Everything works as it should, however the audio is quite glitchy and starts to freeze and cut out which I presume is a result my browser not having the capacity to process all of the audio information at once.

A lot of audio nodes are added to the audiocontext each time a note is played so I'm wondering if unused nodes slow the audiocontext down, if so is there any way to destroy them?

my code:

```
   play = function(s, p) {
        //setup
        var now = AudioContext.currentTime;
        var osc1 = AudioContext.createOscillator(),
            osc2 = AudioContext.createOscillator(),
            osc3 = AudioContext.createOscillator(),
            osc4 = AudioContext.createOscillator(),
            gain1 = AudioContext.createGain(),
            gain2 = AudioContext.createGain(),
            gain3 = AudioContext.createGain(),
            gain4 = AudioContext.createGain(),
            filter = new tuna.Filter(),
            phaser = new tuna.Chorus();
            convolver = new tuna.Convolver();
        var pitch = p
        osc1.type = 'sine';
        osc2.type = 'square';
        osc3.type = 'triangle';
        osc4.type = 'sine';
        osc1.frequency.value = pitch * 1.5
        osc2.frequency.value = pitch * 8
        osc3.frequency.value = pitch
        osc4.frequency.value = pitch/2
        gain1.gain.setValueAtTime(0,now)
        gain2.gain.setValueAtTime(0,now)
        gain3.gain.setValueAtTime(0,now)
        gain4.gain.setValueAtTime(0,now)
        gain1.gain.linearRampToValueAtTime(s[1].value * 1500,now + s[4].value)
        gain2.gain.linearRampToValueAtTime(s[0].value * 1500,now + s[4].value)
        gain3.gain.linearRampToValueAtTime(1,now + s[4].value)
        gain4.gain.linearRampToValueAtTime(s[1].value/2,now + s[4].value)
        gain1.gain.linearRampToValueAtTime(0,now + s[4].value + s[5].value)
        gain2.gain.linearRampToValueAtTime(0,now + s[4].value + s[5].value)
        gain3.gain.linearRampToValueAtTime(0,now + s[4].value + s[5].value)
        gain4.gain.linearRampToValueAtTime(0,now + s[4].value + s[5].value)
        filter.frequency = s[2].value * 2200
        filter.Q = s[0].value * 10
        convolver.wetLevel = s[3].value/10
        phaser.rate = s[3].value/10
        osc3.frequency.value = pitch * 0.666
        osc1.connect(gain1);
        osc2.connect(gain2);
        osc3.connect(gain3);
        osc4.connect(gain4);
        gain1.connect(osc2.frequency);
        gain2.connect(osc3.frequency);
        gain3.connect(filter.input);
        gain4.connect(filter.input)
        filter.output.connect(convolver.input);
        convolver.output.connect(phaser.input);
        phaser.output.connect(AudioContext.destination);
        osc1.start();
        osc2.start();
        osc3.start();
        osc4.start();
        setTimeout(function(){
        osc1.stop();
        osc2.stop();
        osc3.stop();
        osc4.stop();
    }, (s[4].value+s[5].value)*1000)
    }
play([0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4],440);
```

It looks very ugly but I can't think of another way to playback sounds.

I'm using tuna js to create chrorus, reverb and filter.

additionally I would appreciate if any information on how to low-level optimize javascript.

Comment: Try creating your nodes and filters once and reusing them instead of recreating every time you play a note.

To make sure nodes are being destroyed, disconnect from the context.destination when you're finished with them and use debugging tools  (like Chrome's heap snapshot) to check the number of instances of AudioNode, AudioParam etc you have in memory.

Comment: Thanks. As far as I know, reusing nodes is not possible without sacrificing polyphony?

Comment: True, but can you create a pool of 8, 16 or 32 'notes' that you reuse? That would mean you could set them up before the sound starts playing and you will avoid doing those expensive operations every time you play a note.

Comment: Consider removing your setTimeout function.  It looks like you want to stop all 4 oscillators at the time s[4].value+s[5].value seconds.  Just do osc1.stop(s[4].value+s[5].value + now).  This should at least make the oscillators stop at precise times instead of some arbitrary (but small) time later because setTimeout very likely isn't sample accurate.

Comment: What browser are you on? I know that convolvers work poorly on mobile devices, so that might be the cause if you're using one of those.